# Mark diagonal boxes dynamically with OOP in PHP

Tags: php, nested-loops, diagonal

I'm trying to plot an X in the diagonal boxes. The Queen is placed randomly. See image below.

[image]

As you can see only the last X on (5,5) is plotted properly. In this example the  X should be plotted in box (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4) and (5,5). Since the Queen is placed randomly, the method ***markRelatedDiagonalBoxes*** should work dynamically. Below the Board_model. Anyone an idea how to write the markRelatedDiagonalBoxes properly so It will plot the X as described above.

**Board_model.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * This class will handle:
 *  1) Constructing the boards boxes.
 *  2) Returning the property $_row.
 *  3) Returning the property $_col.
 *  4) Returning the property $_box.
 *  5) Setting random rows and columns.
 *  6) Returning all the related boxes.
 *  7) Returning the horizontal related boxes.
 *  8) Returning the vertical related boxes.
 *  9) Returning the diagonal related boxes.
 */
class Board_model extends CI_Model {

    public $randomRow;
    public $randomCol;

    private $_box;
    private $_length;
    private $_row;
    private $_col;

    /**
     * This method 1) will:
     *  1) Set the $_length property.
     *  2) Create an array of new objects, Boxes based on the length of the rows and columns.
     * @param int $length
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('box');
        $this->_length = 7;
        for($row=0; $row < $this->_length; $row++){
            for($col=0; $col< $this->_length; $col++){
                $this->_row = $row;
                $this->_col = $col;
                $this->_box[$row+1][$col+1] = new Box($row+1, $col+1);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * This method 2) will:
     *  1) Return the $_row property.
     * @return int
     */
    public function getRow() {
        return $this->_row;
    }

    /**
     * This method 3) will:
     *  1) Return the $_col property.
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCol() {
        return $this->_col;
    }

    /**
     * This method 4) will:
     *  1) Return the $_box property based on the specified row and column.
     * @param $row
     * @param $col
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBox($row, $col) {
        return $this->_box[$row][$col];
    }

    /**
     * This method 5) will:
     *  1) Randomly choose a number within the rang from 1 to the $_length property and place it in the property $randomRow.
     *  2) Randomly choose a number within the rang from 1 to the $_length property and place it in the property $randomCol.
     *  3) Execute the MarkRelatedHorizontalBoxes method.
     *  4) Execute the MarkRelatedVerticalBoxes method.
     *  5) TODO: Execute the MarkRelatedDiagonalBoxes method.
     */
    public function setRandomColRow() {
        // STATIC RANDOM TEST NUMBER
        //mt_srand(1234534);
        $this->randomRow = mt_rand(1, $this->_length);      
        $this->randomCol = mt_rand(1, $this->_length);

        // Set piece
        $this->getBox($this->randomRow,$this->randomCol)->setPiece("&#9813");

        $this->relatedDiagonalBoxes(); 
        return $this->_box;        
    }

    function object_to_array($object) {
        return (array) $object;
    }

    /**
     * This method 7) will:
     *  1) Create the related vertical array
     *  2) Loop thew the array
     *  3) Get the box position and place and X in the box as piece
     *  4) TODO: Check if the box is empty
     */
    public function markRelatedVerticalBoxes() {  
        for($row = 0; $row < $this->_length; $row++) {                
            $verticalBoxes[$row+1] = $row+1;
            // Delete the random cel out of the array
            unset($verticalBoxes[$this->randomRow]);                
        }
        foreach ($verticalBoxes as $verticalBox) {            
            $this->getBox($verticalBox,$this->randomCol)->setPiece("X");                 
        }            
    }

    /**
     * This method 8) will:
     *  1) Create the related horizontal array
     *  2) Loop thew the array
     *  3) Get the box position and place and X in the box as piece
     */
    public function markRelatedHorizontalBoxes() {
        for($col = 0; $col < $this->_length; $col++) {
            $horizontalBoxes[$col+1] = $col+1;
            // Delete the random cel out of the array
            unset($horizontalBoxes[$this->randomCol]); 
        }
        foreach ($horizontalBoxes as $horizontalBox) {
            $this->getBox($this->randomRow, $horizontalBox)->setPiece("X");
        }
    }

    public function markRelatedDiagonalBoxes() {  

        $row = $this->randomRow - 1;
        $col = $this->randomCol - 1;

        while($row > 0 ) {
            while($col > 0 ) {
                $this->getBox($row, $col)->setPiece("X");
                $col--;
            }
            $row--;  
        }  
    }

    /**
     * This method 9) will: 
     *  1) Create the diagonal array
     *  2) Loop thew the array
     *  3) Get the box position and place and X in the box as piece
     * @return array
     */
    public function relatedDiagonalBoxes() {

        //$this->MarkRelatedHorizontalBoxes();

        //$this->MarkRelatedVerticalBoxes(); 

        $this->markRelatedDiagonalBoxes(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If I move $row-- after $col--, now the system gets into an infinite loop. So that's not the solution. But thanks for taking the time to help me out

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is iterating over rows, then iterating over columns within. You set all of the pieces while reducing columns completely before moving on to the next row.

If you only want to set one piece per row as you would want for a slope you will need to break after placing a piece in a column.

```
while($row > 0) {
    while($col > 0) {
        $this->getBox($row, $col)->setPiece('X');
        $col--;
        break; // placing this break is the logic you are trying to achieve
               // however defeats the purpose of the secondary while loop
    }
    $row--;
}
```

Something like the following should suffice:

```
while($row > 0 && $col > 0) {
    $this->getBox($row--, $col--)->setPiece('X');
}
```

It's the same as you would do to go straight along a row or column, you just need to decrement both values to achieve a slope.